# Zip MD5 depends on file creation time

Tags: md5sum

My build artifact is packed in a archive. And I need a way to check if it's been changed after rebuild by comparing the MD5 (which is the easiest option so far).

So when I pack the same file but with different creation time - archive MD5 changes. So I need to generate a archive which MD5 relies on inner files MD5.

Consider the below snippet as an example:

```
touch file
md5 file
zip -X file.zip  ./file
md5 file.zip
touch file
md5 file
zip -X file.zip  ./file
md5 file.zip
```

My goal to have the same archive MD5 sum for file with the same MD5 sums.

Comment: use tar/gzip instead of zip

Comment: I've tried `tar -c ./file | gzip -n >file.tgz` but It makes no difference for me.